Fix error (BrokenPipeError: [Errno 108] Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown) for usb-gadget
I've been working on a python script to make a bad USB, because I want to prank some friends<  and I got a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W.
import json

NULL_CHAR = chr(0)

def list2string(lst, char="+"):
    out = ""
    for i in lst:
        kc = Get_Keys_From_File(i)
        if kc is None:
            kc = "UNKNOWN"  
        if out == "":
            out += str(kc)
        else:
            out += char + str(kc)
    print(out)
    return out

def write_report(report):
    try:
        with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
            fd.write(report.encode())
    except IOError as e:
        print(f"Error writing to file: {e}")
    print(report)

def Get_Keys_From_File(key):
    try:
        with open('keys.json', 'r') as f2:
            data = json.load(f2)
            values = data.get(key)
            if values is not None:
                return values
            else:
                return None
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("keys.json file not found.")
        return None

def Write_Keys_From_File():
    try:
        with open('ExText.txt', 'r') as f2:
            lines = f2.read().splitlines()
            line_count = len(lines)
            counter = 0
            for line in lines:
                words = line.split()
                if len(words) > 1:
                    joined_text = list2string(words)
                    keycode = Get_Keys_From_File(joined_text)
                else:
                    data = line.strip()
                    keycode = Get_Keys_From_File(data)
                write_report(keycode if keycode is not None else "UNKNOWN")
                counter += 1
                if counter == line_count:
                    break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("ExText.txt file not found.")

Write_Keys_From_File()

And I've been getting this error (BrokenPipeError: [Errno 108] Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown).
I've set up my USB gadget correctly because I had an old script that did preformed keys manually, but I'm working on this one to do something, because I'm bored and want to make it easy to add text.
The JSON list (keys.json)
{
    " ": "NULL_CHAR*32+chr(32)+NULL_CHAR*223",
    "!": "NULL_CHAR*33+chr(33)+NULL_CHAR*222",
    "\"": "NULL_CHAR*34+chr(34)+NULL_CHAR*221",
    "#": "NULL_CHAR*35+chr(35)+NULL_CHAR*220",
    "$": "NULL_CHAR*36+chr(36)+NULL_CHAR*219",
    "%": "NULL_CHAR*37+chr(37)+NULL_CHAR*218",
    "&": "NULL_CHAR*38+chr(38)+NULL_CHAR*217",
    "'": "NULL_CHAR*39+chr(39)+NULL_CHAR*216",
    "(": "NULL_CHAR*40+chr(40)+NULL_CHAR*215",
    ")": "NULL_CHAR*41+chr(41)+NULL_CHAR*214",
    "*": "NULL_CHAR*42+chr(42)+NULL_CHAR*213",
    "+": "NULL_CHAR*43+chr(43)+NULL_CHAR*212",
    ",": "NULL_CHAR*44+chr(44)+NULL_CHAR*211",
    "-": "NULL_CHAR*45+chr(45)+NULL_CHAR*210",
    ".": "NULL_CHAR*46+chr(46)+NULL_CHAR*209",
    "/": "NULL_CHAR*47+chr(47)+NULL_CHAR*208",
    "0": "NULL_CHAR*48+chr(48)+NULL_CHAR*207",
    "1": "NULL_CHAR*49+chr(49)+NULL_CHAR*206",
    "2": "NULL_CHAR*50+chr(50)+NULL_CHAR*205",
    "3": "NULL_CHAR*51+chr(51)+NULL_CHAR*204",
    "4": "NULL_CHAR*52+chr(52)+NULL_CHAR*203",
    "5": "NULL_CHAR*53+chr(53)+NULL_CHAR*202",
    "6": "NULL_CHAR*54+chr(54)+NULL_CHAR*201",
    "7": "NULL_CHAR*55+chr(55)+NULL_CHAR*200",
    "8": "NULL_CHAR*56+chr(56)+NULL_CHAR*199",
    "9": "NULL_CHAR*57+chr(57)+NULL_CHAR*198",
    ":": "NULL_CHAR*58+chr(58)+NULL_CHAR*197",
    ";": "NULL_CHAR*59+chr(59)+NULL_CHAR*196",
    "<": "NULL_CHAR*60+chr(60)+NULL_CHAR*195",
    "=": "NULL_CHAR*61+chr(61)+NULL_CHAR*194",
    ">": "NULL_CHAR*62+chr(62)+NULL_CHAR*193",
    "?": "NULL_CHAR*63+chr(63)+NULL_CHAR*192",
    "@": "NULL_CHAR*64+chr(64)+NULL_CHAR*191",
    "A": "NULL_CHAR*65+chr(65)+NULL_CHAR*190",
    "B": "NULL_CHAR*66+chr(66)+NULL_CHAR*189",
    "C": "NULL_CHAR*67+chr(67)+NULL_CHAR*188",
    "D": "NULL_CHAR*68+chr(68)+NULL_CHAR*187",
    "E": "NULL_CHAR*69+chr(69)+NULL_CHAR*186",
    "F": "NULL_CHAR*70+chr(70)+NULL_CHAR*185",
    "G": "NULL_CHAR*71+chr(71)+NULL_CHAR*184",
    "H": "NULL_CHAR*72+chr(72)+NULL_CHAR*183",
    "I": "NULL_CHAR*73+chr(73)+NULL_CHAR*182",
    "J": "NULL_CHAR*74+chr(74)+NULL_CHAR*181",
    "K": "NULL_CHAR*75+chr(75)+NULL_CHAR*180",
    "L": "NULL_CHAR*76+chr(76)+NULL_CHAR*179",
    "M": "NULL_CHAR*77+chr(77)+NULL_CHAR*178",
    "N": "NULL_CHAR*78+chr(78)+NULL_CHAR*177",
    "O": "NULL_CHAR*79+chr(79)+NULL_CHAR*176",
    "P": "NULL_CHAR*80+chr(80)+NULL_CHAR*175",
    "Q": "NULL_CHAR*81+chr(81)+NULL_CHAR*174",
    "R": "NULL_CHAR*82+chr(82)+NULL_CHAR*173",
    "S": "NULL_CHAR*83+chr(83)+NULL_CHAR*172",
    "T": "NULL_CHAR*84+chr(84)+NULL_CHAR*171",
    "U": "NULL_CHAR*85+chr(85)+NULL_CHAR*170",
    "V": "NULL_CHAR*86+chr(86)+NULL_CHAR*169",
    "W": "NULL_CHAR*87+chr(87)+NULL_CHAR*168",
    "X": "NULL_CHAR*88+chr(88)+NULL_CHAR*167",
    "Y": "NULL_CHAR*89+chr(89)+NULL_CHAR*166",
    "Z": "NULL_CHAR*90+chr(90)+NULL_CHAR*165",
    "[": "NULL_CHAR*91+chr(91)+NULL_CHAR*164",
    "\\": "NULL_CHAR*92+chr(92)+NULL_CHAR*163",
    "]": "NULL_CHAR*93+chr(93)+NULL_CHAR*162",
    "^": "NULL_CHAR*94+chr(94)+NULL_CHAR*161",
    "_": "NULL_CHAR*95+chr(95)+NULL_CHAR*160",
    "`": "NULL_CHAR*96+chr(96)+NULL_CHAR*159",
    "a": "NULL_CHAR*97+chr(97)+NULL_CHAR*158",
    "b": "NULL_CHAR*98+chr(98)+NULL_CHAR*157",
    "c": "NULL_CHAR*99+chr(99)+NULL_CHAR*156",
    "d": "NULL_CHAR*100+chr(100)+NULL_CHAR*155",
    "e": "NULL_CHAR*101+chr(101)+NULL_CHAR*154",
    "f": "NULL_CHAR*102+chr(102)+NULL_CHAR*153",
    "g": "NULL_CHAR*103+chr(103)+NULL_CHAR*152",
    "h": "NULL_CHAR*104+chr(104)+NULL_CHAR*151",
    "i": "NULL_CHAR*105+chr(105)+NULL_CHAR*150",
    "j": "NULL_CHAR*106+chr(106)+NULL_CHAR*149",
    "k": "NULL_CHAR*107+chr(107)+NULL_CHAR*148",
        "l": "NULL_CHAR*108+chr(108)+NULL_CHAR*147",
        "m": "NULL_CHAR*109+chr(109)+NULL_CHAR*146",
        "n": "NULL_CHAR*110+chr(110)+NULL_CHAR*145",
        "o": "NULL_CHAR*111+chr(111)+NULL_CHAR*144",
        "p": "NULL_CHAR*112+chr(112)+NULL_CHAR*143",
        "q": "NULL_CHAR*113+chr(113)+NULL_CHAR*142",
        "r": "NULL_CHAR*114+chr(114)+NULL_CHAR*141",
        "s": "NULL_CHAR*115+chr(115)+NULL_CHAR*140",
        "t": "NULL_CHAR*116+chr(116)+NULL_CHAR*139",
        "u": "NULL_CHAR*117+chr(117)+NULL_CHAR*138",
        "v": "NULL_CHAR*118+chr(118)+NULL_CHAR*137",
        "w": "NULL_CHAR*119+chr(119)+NULL_CHAR*136",
        "x": "NULL_CHAR*120+chr(120)+NULL_CHAR*135",
        "y": "NULL_CHAR*121+chr(121)+NULL_CHAR*134",
        "z": "NULL_CHAR*122+chr(122)+NULL_CHAR*133",
        "{": "NULL_CHAR*123+chr(123)+NULL_CHAR*132",
        "|": "NULL_CHAR*124+chr(124)+NULL_CHAR*131",
        "}": "NULL_CHAR*125+chr(125)+NULL_CHAR*130",
        "~": "NULL_CHAR*126+chr(126)+NULL_CHAR*129",
        "backspace": "NULL_CHAR*127+chr(127)+NULL_CHAR*128",
        "ctrl": "NULL_CHAR*224+chr(0)+NULL_CHAR*1",
        "shift": "NULL_CHAR*224+chr(0)+NULL_CHAR*2",
        "alt": "NULL_CHAR*224+chr(0)+NULL_CHAR*4"
    }


and the template text (ExText.txt)
h
e
l
l
o
ctrl t

I've tried just doing print(keycode), and it prints it normally.
But when I actually supposed to perform the key press, it doesn't do anything.
